# Why does Artinsoft stops in % 39 even if I change the project or resulting format?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to convert a Visual Basic 6 program to 2010 C# using Artinsoft. It always stops after %100 preprocessing percentage and %39 upgrade percentage. I tried different outputs other than 2010 C# like 2005 Basic, 2005 C# but this %39 didn't change. It never finished the upgrade process it always stops on %39 and when I check I see that it creates an inappropriate solution file which does not open (visual studio says so) . In the upgraded folder I check for some other files which maybe converted but I can not find.

In order to find a solution to the conversion problem I am reading the log file. Each time it complains about a different file (form file). To achieve some progress I remove that form completely from my project leaving it in a status which is compileable again and try the upgrade program again using Artinsoft. But nothing changes again %39 upgrade result. I am expecting at least something should change but nothing changes.

During the conversion I accept the default upgrade options, all references are already resolved. What can I do more? I am using the trial version which is limited to 10000 LOC. Thank you for your time. I have been struggling with this for a week. I need some professional help.

F.Ferda Özdemir Sönmez

Comment: Have you asked Artinsoft?

Comment: Wild guess that there is a dependency registration problem, I would try again on a clean PC or VM and see if that makes any difference.